Issue converting FileEntities from Directory.list() to strings
If I have a script like this
import 'package:path/path.dart' as p;
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';

void main() async {
  final inDir = p.join(Directory.current.path, 'tmp', 'in'); // should we rename this
  var dir = Directory(inDir);
  final List<FileSystemEntity> fileList = await dir.list().toList();
  for (var file in fileList.where((entity) => entity is File) ) {
    print ("Processing ${(file as File).toString()}");
    final contents = (file as File).readAsStringSync();
    print (contents);
  }
}

it works fine.
Processing File: 'C:\FlutterProjects\project\tmp\a.txt'
some text

However if I want to get the file path to pass to another function as a string
import 'package:path/path.dart' as p;
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';

void main() async {
  final inDir = p.join(Directory.current.path, 'tmp'); // should we rename this
  var dir = Directory(inDir);
  final List<FileSystemEntity> fileList = await dir.list().toList();
  for (var file in fileList.where((entity) => entity is File) ) {
    print ("Processing ${(file as File).toString()}");
    readFile ((file as File).toString());
  }
}

void readFile (String filePath) {

    final file = File(filePath); 
    final contents = file.readAsStringSync();
    print (contents);

}

... then it doesn't work...
Processing File: 'C:\FlutterProjects\project\tmp\a.txt'
Unhandled exception:
FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'File: 'C:\FlutterProjects\project\tmp\a.txt'' (OS Error: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
, errno = 123)
#0      _File.throwIfError (dart:io/file_impl.dart:675:7)
#1      _File.openSync (dart:io/file_impl.dart:490:5)
#2      _File.readAsBytesSync (dart:io/file_impl.dart:574:18)
#3      _File.readAsStringSync (dart:io/file_impl.dart:624:18)
#4      readFile (file:///C:/FlutterProjects/project/bin/parse-files.dart:18:27)
#5      main (file:///C:/FlutterProjects/project/bin/parse-files.dart:11:5)
<asynchronous suspension>


I am guessing because it  still has File: at the beginning. So I could treat that as an entity in the function itself or I transform the string to not have File: a the beginning but I don't understand why it is not sending the string of the file as a file (which is what I would like to do keep the function more reusable).
TL;DR why doesn't ((file as File).toString()); do what I expect when file is a FileEntity.

The output of calling toString() on a File object are not a path you can use for something. If you see your code, the result of calling toString() on your File are actually the String:
File: 'C:\FlutterProjects\project\tmp\a.txt'

So what you are actually ended up doing, are calling:
File("File: 'C:\FlutterProjects\project\tmp\a.txt'");

Which fails since that is not a valid path and not something you can read from.
Instead of calling toString(), you should use the .path property on the File object. Or just send the File as argument to your method:
import 'package:path/path.dart' as p;
import 'dart:io';

void main() async {
  final inDir = p.join(Directory.current.path, 'tmp'); // should we rename this
  var dir = Directory(inDir);
  final List<FileSystemEntity> fileList = await dir.list().toList();
  
  for (var file in fileList.whereType<File>()) {
    print("Processing ${file.path}");
    readFile(file);
  }
}

void readFile(File file) {
  final contents = file.readAsStringSync();
  print(contents);
}

Also, I have fixed your unneeded casting of file types in this code. If you use whereType, it actually filter based on type checking and returns the right type of objects.

Awesome thanks it was .path that I needed. But the thing I still don't understand is if I have File object and use .toString then it works... So what dies the .. as File .. actually do for the FileEntity?

It is not as File that dies. In your first example you do final contents = (file as File).readAsStringSync(); and you are just calling file.readAsStringSync() here as in my code. Your code, in second example, dies because you are calling toString() and uses that result to attempt creating a new File object, which you can't since it is prefixed with the String "file:".

Sorry dies was an autocorrect typos. I meant what does it do. I know it doesn't die because of this.

File are a subclass of FileSystemEntity. When you do the listing, you get files, directories and other kind of objects back. All of these have FileSystemEntity as common class which is also why your end up getting a List<FileSystemEntity> back. So what your code does it saying: "I know for a fact this object are of the type File so please test for that and if it is true, let me use it as a File". If the object are not a File, your program will crash.

Right so I thought that if I say (entity as File).toString it would give me the string of the file not the entity ie without the File: prefix.

toString() on File returns that file: prefix. It have nothing to do with FileSystemEntity. You should, in general, often not use the output of toString() for other than debug purposes. Check the documentation to be sure and always test if the output are as you expect before using it.

Oh! I thought I'd tested this. Ok that explains it. I'd made the wrong assumption. Thankyou for your patience
